# how to know elastic-search cluster capacity?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, bandwidth

Recently I'm working in a project which requires figuring out elastic-search capacity as we will increase a lot msgs in es system per second.

We have 3 types of nodes in es cluster: master, data, client.

how do we know the maximum insert count per second our client can handle? do we need to care about the bandwidth of the client nodes?

Comment: It is difficult to come up with a proper formula to tell you your max ingestion rate. (szie of the message, complexity of the mapping, type of query, number of nodes, quantity of ram, number of cpu, network latency, type of disk ....) But you could use [EsRally](https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) a tool to perform benchmark on your elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: I realized this later on, thank you, will check EsRally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the above comments, you need to benchmark your cluster hardware and settings with your proposed data structure using a tool like https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/